# Plone: Validate field based on other field's value

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

Let's say we have a dexterity content type with two fields: `field_a` and `field_b`.

In edit mode:

- if `field_a` has the `category_1` value selected then `field_b` is not required
- if `field_b` has other value selected then `field_b` is required

It seems a simple validation is not possible here. I tried:

```
from zope.interface import Invalid

def validate_field_b(value):
    # value is a string here. I can't create a condition based on field_a.
    raise Invalid(_(u"Value in field b is required."))
```

used here:

```
field_b = schema.TextLine(
    title=_(u"Some field B"),
    required=False,
    constraint=validate_field_b
)
```

The result is `field_b` required all the time. :)

Any solution here? How the get the form / context / request / other fields value in my validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use an `invariant` instead of `constraint`:
https://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/validators.html#invariants

```
@invariant
def validate_field_b(data):
    if data.field_a != 'category_1' and data.field_b is None:
        raise Invalid(_("Missing input for field_b."))
```